# How to suppress ambient transaction warning with EF7 RC2

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

How to suppress ambient transaction warning with EF7 RC2?

The **SuppressAmbientTransactionWarning()** method cannot be found.

Comment: Test it and give me plz a feedback if this does not working#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable that in the DbContext(in old versions):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=EFTutorial;Trusted_Connection=True;").SuppressAmbientTransactionWarning();
     base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

or

If you have the connection string in the json:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]).SuppressAmbientTransactionWarning();
```

---

In the new version:

```
  var optionsBuilder = new Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder();
    var extension = new SqlServerOptionsExtension(optionsBuilder.Options.GetExtension<SqlServerOptionsExtension>())
    {
        ThrowOnAmbientTransaction = false
    };

    ((IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure)optionsBuilder).AddOrUpdateExtension(extension);
```

Comment: from @LukasJanecek: CS0117 `SqlServerOptionsExtension` does not contain a definition for `ThrowOnAmbientTransaction`.

Answer (score 12):

While the question was related to RC2, as of Oct 16, 2016, this worked for me and hopefully it is useful to someone else:

```
services.AddDbContext<OpenDataContext>(options =>
   {
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
       options.ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning));
   });
```

Used above in an integration test setup class.

Comment: Does this mean an ambient transaction will not be used?

Comment: I do not believe it would change behavior like that. It suppresses the warning and the warning in my case was causing test failures if I am remembering correctly. For instance, I believe InMemory doesn't support ambient transactions so the warning I was suppressing was done to prevent that warning from failing an integration test. A trade off we were ok with. Not sure why my code sample is spinning up a UseSqlServer though. o.O